# Rails form disable_with option with 2 submit buttons start disabling other button also when i click one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails app i am using three buttons, `save` `submit` and `cancel`. I used `disable_with` option for `save` and `submit` with values `saving...` and `submitting`.

But the problem is when click any `save` or `submit` the other button start showing its `disabled_with` value too. For example, if i click on `save` then `save` become `saving...` and `submit` also become `submitting...`.

Can you have any idea how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer is correct but might not work sometimes with turbolinks, so you can modify it like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_form :submit', function () {
    var buttons = $('.my_form :submit').not($(this));
    buttons.removeAttr('data-disable-with');
    buttons.attr('disabled', true);
});
```

:)

Answer (score 6):

Working for me:

```
$('.my_form :submit').click( function () {
    var buttons = $('.my_form :submit').not($(this));
    buttons.removeAttr('data-disable-with');
    buttons.attr('disabled', true);
});
```